# woocommerce rest API request for purchase single product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

New to woocommerce ,i develop a sale file app , i decide to use woocommerce rest API i can show products

`/wc-api/v2/products`

I know how can add to order

`/wc-api/v2/orders`

How can add product to cart and checkout and connect to bank gateway?

Comment: Do you need a buyNow button,?

Answer (score 0):

The cart is part of a session and is saved in the MySQL table wp_woocommerce_sessions. This table is accessed using a WC_Session_Handler object. AFAIK the WooCommerce REST API does not provide access to WC_Session_Handler objects.

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do but if you want to access the cart through the REST API I think you will need to implement your own REST controller for the wp_woocommerce_sessions table. This isn't that difficult to do as you can modify one of the existing WooCommerce REST controllers to work with WC_Session_Handler objects to access the wp_woocommerce_sessions table.

But, beware a WooCommerce session is bound to a browser session through cookies and you need to handle that binding.